# MULTIPLE JOIN IN MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, multiple-tables, multiple-join-rows

```
SELECT VISA41717.Fraud_Post_Date,
       VISA41717.Merchant_Name_Raw,
       VISA41717.Merchant_City,
       VISA41717.Merchant_Country,
       VISA41717.Merchant_Category_Code,
       VISA41717.ARN,
       VISA41717.POS_Entry_Mode,
       VISA41717.Fraud_Type,
       VISA41717.Local_Amt,
       VISA41717.Fraud_Amt,
       VISA41717.Purch_Date,
       VISA41717.Currency_Code,
       VISA41717.Cashback_Indicator,
       VISA41717.Card_Account_Num,
       BIN.BANK,
       BIN.COUNTRY
FROM ((VISA41717 AS VS)
     LEFT JOIN MASTERCARD_VISA AS MV ON VS.ARN = MV.MICROFILM_NUMBER)
     RIGHT JOIN BIN AS B ON LEFT(Card_Account_Num, 6) = B.INT
WHERE VISA41717.ARN IS NULL
      OR MASTERCARD_VISA.MICROFILM_NUMBER IS NULL
ORDER BY VISA41717.ARN;
```

I tried this code but give me an error

> JOIN EXPRESSION NOT SUPPORTED

Then, I tried this one:

```
SELECT VISA41717.Fraud_Post_Date,
       VISA41717.Merchant_Name_Raw,
       VISA41717.Merchant_City,
       VISA41717.Merchant_Country,
       VISA41717.Merchant_Category_Code,
       VISA41717.ARN,
       VISA41717.POS_Entry_Mode,
       VISA41717.Fraud_Type,
       VISA41717.Local_Amt,
       VISA41717.Fraud_Amt,
       VISA41717.Purch_Date,
       VISA41717.Currency_Code,
       VISA41717.Cashback_Indicator,
       VISA41717.Card_Account_Num,
       BIN.BANK,
       BIN.COUNTRY,
       LEFT(Card_Account_Num, 6) AS VBIN
FROM VISA41717,
     BIN
     LEFT JOIN MASTERCARD_VISA ON (VISA41717.ARN = MASTERCARD_VISA.MICROFILM_NUMBER
                                  AND VBIN = B.INT);
WHERE VISA41717.ARN IS NULL
      OR MASTERCARD_VISA.MICROFILM_NUMBER IS NULL
ORDER BY VISA41717.ARN;
```

Still there's an error

> SYNTAX ERROR IN JOIN OPERATOR

I'am trying to create a table from two different tables.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to remove redundant parentheses in *((VISA41717 AS VS)
     LEFT JOIN MASTERCARD_VISA AS MV ON VS.ARN = MV.MICROFILM_NUMBER)*

Comment: still error ("SYNTAX ERROR IN LEFT(Card_Account_Num, 6) = B.INT") Can you help me with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a `LEFT JOIN` to the query with tables relative to `VISA41717` and even use the string expression directly in the `ON` clause which is viable in MS Access SQL though expressions with constants are not: `ID=7`.

However, with such expressions warnings may rise if you attempt to view the query in *Design View* (assuming you use the GUI program, MSAccess.exe). Do note the required parentheses pairings.

```sql
...
(FROM VISA41717
 LEFT JOIN MASTERCARD_VISA
     ON (VISA41717.ARN = MASTERCARD_VISA.MICROFILM_NUMBER))
 LEFT JOIN [BIN]
     ON (LEFT(VISA41717.Card_Account_Num, 6) = [BIN].[INT])
```

Comment: Hmmm...syntactically this is correct. Please make sure the join columns exist. Check which table holds *Card_Account_Num*. Also, `INT` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) so needs to be escaped with brackets or back ticks. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

When things get too convoluted, it might help to create a query that delivers the required fields:

```
SELECT *, LEFT(Card_Account_Num, 6) As Card_Account_Num6
FROM VISA41717
WHERE ARN IS NULL
```

Now you can use the query GUI designer with this query and table BIN as source.